# set mac iptables to allow external traffic for AWS MySQL

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench

I am using mac os x mountain lion. I need to configure `MySQL Workbench` to access my db on AWS.

After installing `MySQL Workbench` and trying to connect I get the error `"Host ..... is not allowed to connect to this mysql server"`. After searching online for answers, I found [someone had a similar problem](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=343082&#343082) where the apparent solution is

> 1. Mysql needs to be up and running and bound to listen on any IP.
> 2. Software firewalls need to be disabled or configured to allow external traffic (iptables on linux, windows firewall on windows)
> 3. Security group needs to have a rule to allow your ip address to access the instance on port 3306

So I got step one working. But I don't know how to check whether my `iptable` is configured to allow external traffic or how to set it to do so. Is anyone here able to help me out?